# java access the data in an ArrayList in the main() from another separate class

Tags: java, class, arraylist

How to access the data in an ArrayList in the main() from another separate class? I've finished a programm and it works well now.

However, I need to separate Hammer, ThreeWhiteSoliders and GoldenCross in another class and package them together, which means I need 4 java files together.

However, when I'm trying to do this, I cannot pass the data in the ArrayList to the Hammer class.
My code for the Hammer part now is here so far. Thanks so much.
dataArr is an ArrayList with String[].

```
      if (mtd == 1) {
        int ih, jh;
        jh = 0;
        for (ih = 1; ih < dataArr.size(); ih++) {
            double openh, closeh, highh, lowh, upperwickh, lowerwickh, bodyh;
            openh = Double.parseDouble(dataArr.get(ih)[1]);
            highh = Double.parseDouble(dataArr.get(ih)[2]);
            lowh = Double.parseDouble(dataArr.get(ih)[3]);
            closeh = Double.parseDouble(dataArr.get(ih)[4]);
            upperwickh = highh - closeh;
            lowerwickh = openh - lowh;
            bodyh = closeh - openh;
            if (bodyh > 0 && lowerwickh > 2 * bodyh && bodyh > 5 * upperwickh && ih > indexst && ih < indexed) {
                jh++;
                System.out.println("Pattern Hammer Found at: " + dataArr.get(ih)[0]);
            }
        }
        if (jh == 0)
            System.out.println("Pattern Hammer Not Found");
    }
```

Comment: You gave us too much code for a single question IMO.  Please pare down your question to say 10-20 lines of code, and highlight where we should be looking.  Most folks on SO won't take the time to read through the entire code snippet as is.

Comment: Sorry for that=.= It's my first time to raise a question. I'm going to highlight it now. Thanks.

Comment: Make your ArrayList a static member of the class, not the method. Then you can access it from other classes by using appropriate class name and ArrayList identifier. That's one of the possible options.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..